# Komma innerhalb Striche

Tags: comma

Welche Variante ist richtig?

1. Diese Katze – das mag aber ein Kater sein – die meinen Buchweizen gefressen hat, hat bestraft zu werden.
2. Diese Katze – das mag aber ein Kater sein, – die meinen Buchweizen gefressen hat, hat bestraft zu werden.

Comment: Also meine Katze mag keinen Buchweizen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gemäß amtlichem Regelwerk (siehe Ende von [Abschnitt *2.4 Gedankenstrich*](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6204#)) gilt:

> Satzzeichen, die zum einschließenden Satz gehören und daher auch bei Weglassen des Zusatzes oder Nachtrags stehen müssten, dürfen nicht weggelassen werden.
>
> *Er behauptete – so eine Frechheit! –, dass er im Kino gewesen wäre. Sie hat das – erinnerst du dich nicht? – gestern gesagt.*
>
> *Sie betonte – ich weiß es noch ganz genau –, dass sie für einen Erfolg nicht garantieren könne.* Vgl.: *Sie betonte, dass sie für einen Erfolg nicht garantieren könne.*

Richtig ist demnach nur:

> Diese Katze – das mag aber ein Kater sein –, die meinen Buchweizen gefressen hat, hat bestraft zu werden.